# Adding labels into JSON

Tags: python, json

Is there a quick way to easily convert json?

So I need to convert the following

```
{
    "zapp0a": [
        "192.168.161.22",
        "00:16:3e:16:d9:80"
    ],
    "zapp09": [
        "192.168.161.42",
        "00:16:3e:3a:06:6c"
    ]
}
```

to something that looks like the following

```json
{
    "zapp0a": {
        "ip_address": "192.168.161.22",
        "mac_address": "00:16:3e:16:d9:80"
    },
    "zapp09": {
        "ip_address": "192.168.161.42",
        "mac_address": "00:16:3e:3a:06:6c"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use json module in python, convert list to dict and write back as json:

```
import json
s = your_json_string
d = json.loads(s)
d1 = {}
for i, j in d.items():
    d1.update({i: dict(zip(['ip_address', 'mac_address'],j))})
json.dumps(d1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested dict comprehension to create a dict from the inner lists

```
>>> {i: dict(zip(['ip_address', 'mac_address'], j)) for i,j in data.items()}
{
    'zapp0a': {
        'ip_address': '192.168.161.22',
        'mac_address': '00:16:3e:16:d9:80'},
     'zapp09': {
        'ip_address': '192.168.161.42',
        'mac_address': '00:16:3e:3a:06:6c'
    }
}
```